# How to get the values from DB and store it in a existing excel file using java?

Tags: java, mysql, excel

I want to store the values from the database to an **existing** excel file. For example if the file is stored in `C: data.xls`. I want the data from db table to be stored in that. 
I will mention the column name in the excel file itself.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Would you consider a CSV file, or is your heart set on an Excel file?

Comment: *"Please help me in doing this."*  Which part are you having trouble with?  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  It almost seems like you are asking if someone will "gimme' da' codez?".

Comment: i could able to get the values from database and create a xl file and store it in that . am trying to store it in an existing excel file .

Answer (score 2):

Use `JDBC API` to read/fetch result from the MySql database and [jExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) `(recommended)` to write/update excel document.

Comment: I would second the recommendation for Apache POI its an excellent piece of code, in many ways superior to Microsofts own .COM API.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a CSV file is probably the easiest way to do this.  CSV files can be opened up in Excel, but cannot have any text formatting.  See the [CSV Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) for more details on the format.

If you would rather use an XLS or XLSX format, consider using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), as the formats of those file types (particularly XLS) is quite complicated to write to manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for a CSV file, you need only open the file, and begin putting rows, one per line, with commas in between values. It's very simple, and works with a variety of software.

Comment: *"commas in between values"*  What if the values contain commas?  ;)

Comment: Ok, it's slightly more complicated than that, but still ridiculously simple. It's the kind of code you write once in a given language, and never have to modify again. ^_^

Comment: OK I'll concede that. :)  +1 for the concept of CSV and the last sentence in your comment.